# Cloudflare R2 bucket access using postman

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-r2

I am looking for how to access the Cloudflare R2 bucket in Postman so i can understand and use it in my way.

In other words; i want to know how can i access the r2 bucket and objects using the r2 url without any custom domain:
https://{{account-id}}.r2.cloudflarestorage.com

I read the documentation here:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/examples/postman/

but, i could not get any success.

also they provided a postman collection to test with; but this is also not working for me after following every steps they told. (these all steps are in the same link above)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: cloudflare has its own community you can ask from there.

Comment: {{r2-object}} is collection variable. 1. Export Collection and 2.Import Collection in your work Space. 3. Click ... (left of collection name) 4. Select Edit. 5.  Click Variables Tab 6. Copy 'account-id', 'r2-access-key-id','r2-secret-access-key', 'r2-bucket' and 'r2-object' from your Cloudflare Dashboad. 7. Press Send Button of Postman for Get 'ListBUckets' API.